# Python# rearranging array with high and low element in list?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am new in python i would like to rearranging list with sequence of high and low value. Example Input is a=[1,2,3,4,5] then output should be 
a=[5,1,4,2,3].i solved this way any one have better solution? please guide me.Thank you in Advance.

```
number=int(input("how many number do you want to input?"))
number_list=[]
for i in range(number):
    array=int(input())
    number_list.append(array)

print(number_list)
# empty array for adding value in list
tmp=[]
i=0

m=len(number_list)
while i<m:
    # when last element left in array it will add on our tmp list
    if i > len(number_list):
        tmp.extend(number_list)
        # once all value add in array it will break the program
        if len(tmp) == m:
            break
    else:
        high=max(number_list)
        low=min(number_list)


        tmp.append(high)
        tmp.append(low)
        #number_list.remove(high)
        #number_list.remove(low)
# remove the element after added in the list
        number_list.remove(high)
        number_list.remove(low)
        #print(len(number_list))
        #print(tmp)


    i +=1


print(tmp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really easy, using a basic `for`-loop and a helper list. You are overthinking it:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list1.sort()
resultList = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    resultList.append(list1[len(list1)-1-i])
    resultList.append(list1[i])

resultList = resultList[:len(resultList)//2]
list1 = resultList
```

Now, if you try to print it:

```
print(list1)     # [5, 1, 4, 2, 3]
```

---

*Note: This only works for Python 3, you have to do minor adjustments for it to work with Python 2 as well*

Comment: Which part does only work for python3? Looks perfectly valid python 2 to me too. Additionally, instead of discarding half list, it would be better to save computational resources by `for i in range(len(list1)//2)`.

Comment: It wouldn't work, it depends on the parity of the length of the list. @ImanolLuengo Was `//` present in Python 2 as well?

Comment: @ImanolLuengo it outputs `[5,1,4,2]` for the example list if I use `range(len(list1)//2)`

Comment: `range(len(list1)//2+1)` should solve that. `//` is integer division in both python2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

My adea is to combine two lists alternatively b and c, the first is an order descending of list a, and the scond in order ascending of a

```
import itertools
b=sorted(a, reverse=True)  
c=sorted(a)
print [x for x in itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.izip_longest(b,c)) if x][:len(a)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Aother approach using `min()`, `max()` and a generator:

```
# list passed in argument must be sorted
def get_new_list(a):
    for k in range(int(len(a)/2)+1):
        aa = max(a[k:len(a)-k])
        bb = min(a[k:len(a)-k])
        if aa != bb:
            yield aa
            yield bb
        else:
            yield aa


a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a.sort() 
final = list(get_new_list(a))

print(final)
```

Another approach using `for loop`  and `list slicing`. This approach is more efficient than using `min()` and `max()`:

```
def get_new_list(a):
    for k in range(int(len(a)/2)+1):
        aa = a[k:len(a)-k]
        if len(aa) > 1:
            yield aa[-1]
            yield aa[0]
        else:
            yield aa[0]


a = [5,1,2,3,4]
# list must be sorted 
a.sort()
final = list(get_new_list(a))
print(final)
```

Both will output:

```
[5, 1, 4, 2, 3]
```